# How to search for specific text only in uncommitted changes since last commit in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, search, visual-studio-code, source-control

I have made changes to my repository and I can see the changes of the files under `Source control` in this tab on the left of VS Code. This shows all my **uncommitted** changes in `git`.

[image: Repository changes]

I have a compilation fail because of these **uncommitted** changes but the error is cryptic and misleading. I would like to narrow down the list of files to search to only my **uncommitted** changes.

I would like to search for text only in these **uncommitted**  changes and not the rest of the repo that I can achieve using <kbd>Command</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (as I get more hits than I need).

Is there a way to limit the search only in the changes since the last commit?

I am running on **Windows** but other systems could help.

Comment: does the search term you are searching for have to occur in a changed hunk of the file from that commit, or just anywhere in that file? what OS are you running vscode on? I can conceive of cli options for doing this, but anything integrated into a particular client will be a feature of that client.

Comment: I am looking for the text in uncommitted changes. I am running on Windows. Let me clarify that.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible by default. There's been a [highly upvoted issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/20530) hanging around for years now. I don't see any helpful extensions either.

What you can do as a rather bad workaround:

- close all opened files
- go to `Source Control` in sidebar panel (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>)
- <kbd>Right mouse click</kbd> on `Changes` label and `Open changed files`:

[image: Changed files menu]

- search in opened files (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> -> `...` icon -> `Search only in open editors` book icon):

[image: Search menu]